# Disable the Analytics service for Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

We mirgrated from GCM to FCM without any problems. The notification service is running very well. However, we have to disable the app measurement part of the Firebase Analytics service for legal reasons.

We used this guide to disable the analytics part
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics

So we put this flag to the manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value=false />
```

and we also disabled the collection programmatically:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
```

Unfortunately, data is still collected and we can see new events in the Firebase Analytics Console. Is there any possibility to turn off the analytics services completely?

Thanks for your help.

Edit: I also have the deactivation meta-data in the application tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value=true />
```

Comment: have you tried this?
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value=true />

Comment: Do you only have an app for Android? If so, have you also tried what @lal mentioned? If you've tried everything that was already mentioned in the docs, I suggest you contact Firebase Support directly. They are very good when it comes to providing support with developers.

Comment: Yes - sorry; forgot to mention - I have this in the application tag <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated"
            android:value="true"/>

Comment: I wrote the Firebase Support team. Thanks @AL. for that suggestion.

Comment: No worries. If ever they provided you with a solution and it's not that ***sensitive*** info, do post your answer here and accept it. It might help a random user someday. :)

Answer (score 9):

As of Oct 2017, deactivated value must be "true". "false" won't work anymore.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated"
        android:value="true" />
```

The log shows correctly that it's working.

```
10-11 16:29:32.755 27857-27857/? I/FA: Collection disabled with firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated=1
```

Comment: The problem is this does not fully turn off app measurement.  The log might say, "Event not sent since app measurement is disabled", but the AppMeasurementService is still started and it connects to app-measurement.com according to my software firewall.  If an override is added to completely remove the AppMeasurementService from the manifest, the log shows this error "E/FA: Unable to use remote or local measurement implementation. Please register the AppMeasurementService in the app manifest"

Comment: The behavior of connecting to app-measurement.com is only seen on devices that don't have Google Play services (Google APIs).

Answer (score 6):

This is a Firebase bug or an error in the  [documentation for disabling Analytics collection](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics#permanently_deactivate_collection). To permanently disable collection set `firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated` to **false** (not true):

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated"
        android:value="false" />
```

You can confirm that collection is disabled by enabling Analytics logging:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

and observing output such as this:

```
I/FA: Collection disabled with firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated=1
D/FA: Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
```

Comment: Exactly. See the answer from the Firebase team.

Answer (score 5):

In order to fully disable Analytics from the Firebase Messaging you need to exclude the analytics packages in gradle:

```
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core'
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-analytics'
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-measurement-connector'
}
```

And also deactivate tracking in the AndroidManifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

If you are using proguard then you have to also add this line to the configuration file

```
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.AnalyticsConnector
```

I hope this helps everyone else that does not want to include any form of tracking in their app but still use Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: This looks very interesting, maybe even for APK size saving. Where is this documented please? The docs only mention the meta data flag

Comment: This code is from Signal, the private messenger app https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/blob/master/app/build.gradle https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/blob/master/app/proguard/proguard-firebase-messaging.pro

Answer (score 3):

I tried putting that line in my manifest, **inside** the application tag, **as the first line under the application tag** :

```
 <application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:name="your.package.name">
    <meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

When doing so, during the init, Firebase display in the logs:

**I/FA: Collection disabled with firebase_analytics_collection_enabled=0**

And it seems not to report anything to firebase afterwards.

Comment: Yes; I tried this; forgot to mention - I have this in the application tag but with the value in brackets: android:value="true "

Comment: I have true with no quotes, that might be the difference. One might be a string and the answered parsed as a boolean.

Comment: That sounds promising - Unfortunately, I can not compile without quotes: "Attribute value expected".

Comment: Fair enough, actually I do have quotes, but when I copy paster for some reason they disappear, my bad. 
I spent 30 minutes of trials and error before findings a solution, let me update the answer.

Comment: Let me know if it helped (^_^)

Comment: Nice suggestion. I only had the firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated meta-data in the manifest and used the setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false) call programmatically. With firebase_analytics_collection_enabled in the manifest it seems to work. I get the log information - Collection disabled with firebase_analytics_collection_enabled=0

Comment: Glad it worked, ands it seems aligned with the answer from the firebase team :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just received feedback from the Firebase support team.

> The code for manifest file won't compile if you don't add a double
>   quote in the android:value attribute, good job if you've already added
>   that.
>
> Temporarily disabling the analytics collection should work, could you
>   please try to enable the verbose debug option and check the logs?
>
> On the other hand, we are aware that there's an issue with disabling
>   the analytics collection permanently, there's already a bug filed for
>   this and being prioritized by our engineers appropriately. Please keep
>   updated with our release notes for further notice regarding this
>   issue.
>
> We apologise for any inconvenience that this may have caused you, and
>   we appreciate your understanding as we continue to improve our
>   services, moving forward.